# Django can't find a module when imported from urls.py

Tags: django

I'm having an issue importing another `urlpatterns`.

`python manage.py shell` -> `from bar.urls import urlpatterns` is working fine but Django doesn't find `bar` when I try to import it from `foo/foo/urls.py` : "No module named bar.urls".

`tree ~/workdir/foo`

```
foo
├── foo
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── local_db
│   │   └── foo.db
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── wsgi.py
├── __init__.py
├── manage.py
├── bar
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── baz
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── baz_interface.py
│   │   ├── test.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── index.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── README.md
└── requirements.txt

5 directories, 28 files
```

`foo/urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        (r'^test/', include('foo.bar.urls')),
)

# this will fail too :
# 1.
# from foo.bar.urls import urlpatterns as test
# urlpatterns += test
# 2.
# from bar.urls import urlpatterns as test
# urlpatterns += test
# 3.
#urlpatterns = patterns('',
#    (r'^test/', include('bar.urls')),
#)
```

`bar/urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^$', 'foo.bar.views.viewname', name='viewname'),
)
```

I'm running `Django 1.4.3` on `Python 2.7.3` in a virtualenv.
`bar` is in my `INSTALLED_APPS`.
`~/workdir/foo/` is in my python path.

How can I make my `urlpattern` import from `foo/foo/urls.py` work?

Thank you.

Comment: is ~/workdir also in your python path? if yes, get rid of it...

Comment: @mawimawi no, only `~/workdir/foo` and my virtualenv path.    `url(r'^$', 'bar.views.viewname', name='viewname')` in `foo/urls.py` works though but I would rather include `bar.urls`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `bar/urls.py` should look like:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('bar.views',
    url(r'^$', 'viewname', name='viewname'),
)
```

Your `foo/urls.py` is:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^test/', include('bar.urls')),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check you check `sys.path` variable after your app started, your will see that your first path in list is: `foo` - root directory.  If I understand you right, you can may path something like

```
   sys.path.insert(0, '..')
```

It's very bad solution, more better is:

```
   PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))   
   sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '..')
```

Best solution is create one more `foo` directory above your `foo`'s. And project as:

```
python foo/manage.py runserver
```